# How to fix an image when the window is resized?

Tags: html, css

When I resize the window, the image moves out of place and so therefore overlaps the other div. What do I do so that the image is set in place?

This is what my website looks like when the window is full size [image: 1]

Then when I resize the screen, the image has now overlapped the div. [image: 2]

I've managed to make the title div responsive, but not sure how to fix the image issue.

This is my **index.js** file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import openLips from '../ComingSoon/img/openLips.png';

import '../ComingSoon/styles.scss';

class ComingSoon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comingSoon">
        <div className="openLips">
          <img src={openLips} alt="Open lips"/>
        </div>
        <div className="comingSoonBorder">
          <p className="comingSoonText">Stay tuned<br/>
          Something is on the way</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComingSoon;
```

This is my **styles.scss** file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'ObelixPro';
    src: url('../../fonts/ObelixPro/ObelixPro.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../../fonts/ObelixPro/ObelixPro.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../../fonts/ObelixPro/ObelixPro.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../../fonts/ObelixPro/ObelixPro.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../../fonts/ObelixPro/ObelixPro.svg#ObelixPro') format('svg');
}

body {
    background-color: #E4C938;
}

.comingSoon {
    margin: auto;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.openLips {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 61%;
}

.comingSoonBorder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 80vh;
    border: 7px solid black;
    background-color: white;
}

.comingSoonText {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'ObelixPro';
    font-size: 7vh;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `position:absolute` if you expect the document to reflow when the window is resized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the tongue into `.comingSoonBorder` and position it relative to that container. It will now move with whenever the page width/height changes. In addition set it's width/height using `vh`, so it they will change when the width of the `.comingSoonBorder` element changes.

```js
const openLips = 'https://i.ibb.co/SK4pdjz/tongue-clipart-animated-4-transparent.png';

class ComingSoon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="comingSoon">
        <div className="comingSoonBorder">
          <img className="openLips" src={openLips} alt="Open lips"/>
          <p className="comingSoonText">Stay tuned<br/>
          Something is on the way</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComingSoon />,
  demo
)
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #E4C938;
}

.comingSoon {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.openLips {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(70%, -70%);
  width: 40vh;
  height: 40vh;
  background-size: cover;
}

.comingSoonBorder {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80vh;
  border: 7px solid black;
  background-color: white;
}

.comingSoonText {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'ObelixPro';
  font-size: 7vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo">
  </demo>
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much! This has worked brilliantly!! Literally a life saver 

Answer (score 0):

Make the img tag have the className `openLips` and remove the div tag around the img and move the img tag into the `comingSoonBorder` div.

Change the render() to:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="comingSoon">
      <div className="comingSoonBorder">
        <p className="comingSoonText">Stay tuned<br/>
        Something is on the way</p>
        <img className="openLips" src={openLips} alt="Open lips"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Update .openLips styles:

```
.openLips {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: -105%;
  left: 92%;
  height: 80vh;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/149bdnw6/3/ (not with the same Stones image).

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped me figure out where I was going wrong